# C interfaces and implementations: why there are both function assert and macro assert?

Tags: c, macros

In the "C Interfaces and Implementations" 4.3, in assert.h:

```
#undef assert
#ifdef NDEBUG
#define assert(e) ((void)0)
#else
#include "except.h"
extern void assert(int e);
#define assert(e) ((void)((e)||(RAISE(Assert_Failed), 0)))
#endif
```

What is the purpose of `extern void assert(int e);`? since in `assert.c`, it is implemented by the `assert` macro.

Comment: What is in assert.c and except.h?

Comment: void (assert)(int e) 
{
    assert(e);
}

Comment: @self: The question is clear, he is asking why both macro and function (definition of which is again a macro) for `assert` are defined.

Comment: @brokenfoot Yes I know that. So? Normal asserts don't need both.

Comment: So that if you later do `#undef assert`, you can still `assert(condition)`. Note that `#undef assert` is undefined behavior, so an implementation that does this is doing so out of the kindness of its heart and not due to any obligation.

Comment: Hanson seems to want to present `assert()` as a function implementing an interface (since the book is "C Interfaces and Implementations"), and I guess a macro didn't fit his definition of an interface. But, you do have to jump through some hoops to use the function implementation, and if you do then your program will break if you define `NDEBUG`.

Comment: @brokenfoot Yes, that's what i mean.

Comment: @Raymond Chen: thanks, that make some sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the section of the book carefully, you'll see that it provides the standard interface to `assert()` but does not provide a standard-compliant implementation.

> The `Assert` interface defines `assert(e)` as specified by the standard, except that an assertion failure raises the exception `Assert_Failed` instead of of aborting execution, and does not provide the text of the assertion *e*.
>
> *…extract from `assert.h` shown in question…*
>
> `assert` mimics the standard's definitions so that the two `assert.h` headers can be used interchangeably, which is why `Assert_Failed` appears in `except.h`.  The implementation of this interface is trivial:
>
> #### assert.c
>
> ```
> #include "assert.h"
>
> const Except_T Assert_Failed = { "Assertion failed" };
>
> void (assert)(int e) {
>     assert(e);
> }
> ```

You need to read the earlier part of the chapter to understand the exception handling mechanisms and `Except_T` (and `except.h`).

Comment: Do we need to include "except.h" in "assert.c" ? If NDEBUG is defined, "except.h" is not included in "assert.h" and thus not included in "assert.c", there is compilation error since Except_T is not visible.

Comment: I'd probably argue that the code in `assert.c` should unconditionally `#undef NDEBUG` at the top. It makes no sense to compile the implementation of assert handling as if assertions would never be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Although it looks as it doesn't make sense, it does - at least in some cases.

The `assert()` macro hides the standard definition, but there is still a "backdoor".

```
assert(1 == 0)
```

will call the macro while you can still reach the original function (if defined) through

```
(assert)(1 == 0)
```

(parentheses suppress macro expansion).